# Getting error The tasks argument included a null value. Parameter name: tasks in Task parallel library with parallel.foreach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I am trying to execute multiple tasks which internally calls some http calls.
Problem is when i am using Parallel.ForEach loop I am getting error:

> The tasks argument included a null value. Parameter name: tasks

```
List<Task> TskList = new List<Task>();

Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), row =>
//foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{

    var oTsk =
        new Task(
            () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    some http call
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    //AppendTextBox(row["ssub_msisdn"] as string + ", Error: " + ex.Message, txtBoxResponse);
                }
            });
    TskList.Add(oTsk);
    oTsk.Start();
}
);

var t = Task.WhenAll(TskList.ToArray());
try
{
    await t;
}
catch { }

if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
{
    SetLabel("Completed", lblProcessingStatus);
}
else if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
{ SetLabel("Faulted", lblProcessingStatus); }
```

Comment: You do not need to use `Parallel.ForEach` or `Task.Run` to do http requests in parallel. Show us the `some http call` code and we can show you how to improve this.

Comment: @KamranShahid: Please describe what you're actually trying to do. There's a lot of red flags in this code: the `Task` constructor and `Task.Start` should never be used; HTTP calls are I/O-based and should not require `Parallel.ForEach`; there's an empty catch block; and the code is using `Task.Status` for something other than debugging.

Comment: @StephenCleary: The catch block was trting to add the error message to the TextBox, but since the call was done from a background thread, this did never actually work, so the call was commented out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the list `TskList` from different threads without any synchronization. This can lead to any kind of problems.

Just do this:

```
var tasks = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            // some http call
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // rewrap the needed information into your custom exception object
            throw YourException(ex, row["ssub_msisdn"]);
        }
    });

// now you are at the UI thread
foreach (var t in tasks)
{
    try
    {
        await t;
    }
    catch (YourException ex)
    {
        AppendTextBox(ex.SsubMsisdn + ", Error: " + ex.InnerException.Message, txtBoxResponse);
    }
}
```

`Task.Run` will start the task on the thread pool, you don't actually need `Parallel.ForEach`.

---

Actually, if your code in `try` is only making a http call, you shouldn't need `Task` at all! You can avoid threads altogether by using an async version, e. g. `HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync` or `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync` + `Stream.CopyToAsync`.

E. g.:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); // maybe configure it

async Task ProcessRow(Row row) // put here the correct type
{
    try
    {
        var str = await client.GetStringAsync(row[address]);
        AppendTextBox(str, txtBoxResponse);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        AppendTextBox(row["ssub_msisdn"] + ", Error: " + ex.Message, txtBoxResponse);
    }
}

var tasks = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => ProcessRow(row));
await Yask.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Implemented with a slight variation. Thanks a lot Vlad

Comment: @KamranShahid: You are welcome! But have a look at the last paragraph of the answer (just added).

Comment: That call is a sample code. in real i am also updating some ui element (via invokerequired) along with http call sending and when result is received for the http call e.t.c.

Comment: @KamranShahid: If you switch to async version, you'll stay in the UI thread and won't need InvokeRequired :)